# how to make randomly parameters of transmission animation for image

Tags: android, translate-animation

currently my image is moving by fix points. but now i am trying to change my **y-axis** by randomly. so that image will be move randomly.

i am using it.

```
    final TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(1124.0f, -500.0f,0.0f, 0.0f);   //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
    animation.setDuration(6000);  // animation duration 

    final TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(-100.0f, 1124.0f,y1, y2);   //  new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
    animation2.setDuration(3000);  // animation duration 

animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            System.out.println("animation End");
            rocketImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            stopBlink();
        //  rocketImageup.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                   @Override
                   public void run() {

                    //   y1 = y1 + 50;
                     // y2 = y2+ 50;
                       //replace(-100.0f, 1124.0f,y1, y2);
                      rocketImage2.startAnimation(animation2); 
                       rocketImage2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                   }
                 }, 4000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("animation repeat");
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            System.out.println("animation start");

            if(mp!= null) mp.release();
            mp =MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.rocket_pass); 
            mp.start();
            leftFlag=false;
            startBlink(rocketImage,leftFlag);
        }});
```